# Error while executing a method in Ruby using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, page-object-gem

I am getting the following error when I execute the below code.

Please let me know the way to execute the method 'startup' in Eclipse.

**Error Message**:

> ': undefined local variable or method `***startup***' for PageObjects:Class (NameError) from C:/Technical/RubyTraining/PageObjects.rb:1:in`'

Code:

```
class PageObjects

require 'selenium-webdriver'

require 'page-object'


 def startup

   @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

   @browser.manage.window.maximize

 end

  startup


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have provided, you don't need the class `PageObjects` (If you have more code, please post them all at once). So you might simply try this:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
# require 'page-object' # You are not using page-object either.

def startup
  @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  @browser.manage.window.maximize
end

startup
```

However, if you want to use this class, you need to call this instance method `setup` outside your class after initializing the class. Like this:

```
class PageObjects
  require 'selenium-webdriver'
  require 'page-object'

   def startup
    @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @browser.manage.window.maximize
   end
end

PageObjects.new.startup
```